# Как поставить webhook на бота aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, deploy, webhook

Я арендовал сервер, потом запустил бота на long polling - все работает
Теперь пытаюсь настроить его на вебхук

Я создал сертификат следующими командами, на линукс сервере:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
openssl genrsa -out webhook_pkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key webhook_pkey.pem -out webhook_cert.pem
```

Получил 2 файла
[image: то что получилось]

**Теперь пытаюсь переделать код на webhook** Как я могу это сделать (для примера буду использовать простого эхо-бота)

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import os

# import config
# from config import TOKEN

TOKEN = ":AAHfg0gfUdMYFmeHoWp,h,kegGtQKhLVtmQ"
WEBHOOK_HOST = '81.nnn.1nnn6.23b'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 443  # 443, 80, 88 или 8443 (порт должен быть открыт!)
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'  # На некоторых серверах придется указывать такой же IP, что и выше

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = '/root/tet/webhook_cert.pem'  # Путь к сертификату
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = '/root/tet/webhook_pkey.pem'  # Путь к приватному ключу

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (TOKEN)


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL_BASE)


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    await bot.delete_webhook()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nНапиши мне что-нибудь!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def process_help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Напиши мне что-нибудь, и я отпрпавлю этот текст тебе в ответ!")


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)

executor.start_webhook(
    dispatcher=dp,
    webhook_path="",
    on_startup=on_startup,
    on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    skip_updates=True,
    host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
    port=443)
```

этот код взят из туториала по хероку. Как переделать его под свой сервак?

Answer (score 0):

Вот может это поможет, понять: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gw-cVvsaOGE
А так смысл, такой. Сначала надо сделать запуск бота как сервис через systemd например. создать файл например aiogram_bot.service, такого содержания:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Aiogram bot service
After=multi-user.target 

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/aio/serv_aio.py
     
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Сделать запуск его автоматом после перезагрузки:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable aiogram_bot.service
```

Запустить сервис бота:

```
sudo systemctl start aiogram_bot.service
```

Проверить статус:

```
sudo systemctl status
```

Дальше настроить NGINX на переадресацию на этот сервис.
Создать файл в /etc/nginx/sites-available/ по названию вашего домена например "you_site" и поместить туда примерную конфигурацию:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl you_site;
    listen [::]:443 ssl you_site;

    server_name you_site;

    location /aio {  # Path по которому будет идти переадресация, ваш WEBHOOK_URL
        proxy_pass                          http://localhost:3001;  # здесь как раз укажем где работает запущенный сервис бота
        proxy_set_header                    Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    }
....
}
```

Перезапустить Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

или так

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Конфигурация файла если взять отсюда:
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html
будет примерно такая:

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'you_site'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/aio'

WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'  # or ip
WEBAPP_PORT = 3001
...
```

Написал на скорую руку, могут быть ошибки, главное думаю Вас направить в нужном направлении.)